# Usage of "As Spotted By"

Tags: word-choice, licensing

If I take a look at the usage of the verb "*notice*":

> 1. ***As noticed by*** some customers, the store does not stock the ...
> 2. Some customers ***noticed*** that the store does not stock the...

I will find that I cannot write the following using the verb "*spot*":

> 3. ***As spotted by*** some customers, the store does not stock the ...
> 4. Some customers ***spotted*** that the store does not stock the...

It seems that the verb "*spot*" cannot be followed by a *that*-clause.

But then, I saw this usage of the verb "*spot*" in this [article](http://gizmodo.com/as-spotted-by-9to5mac-apple-will-trim-its-iphone-retur-1542062963):

> ***As spotted by*** 9to5Mac, Apple will trim its iPhone return window from 30 days to 14 as of tomorrow. Carriers had previously offered 14 days, so now at least it's consistent across the board. Still, for Apple Store customers, that's less than half the time to decide if parallax effect is right for you.

Could the sentence in the article be wrong?

Comment: Why the verb "spot" can't be followed by a that-clause?

Comment: Do you have a source for your examples to support your conclusion "It seems that the verb "spot" cannot be followed by a that-clause."?

Comment: @user3169 So, I could write: "*I spotted that she was smiling*"?

Comment: I asked because I haven't seen such as usage ("spot" followed by a "that" clause) that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Could the sentence in the [article](http://gizmodo.com/as-spotted-by-9to5mac-apple-will-trim-its-iphone-retur-1542062963) be wrong?

Well, it could be, but it is not.

{EDIT: In addition, your #3 and #4 are grammatical. But the problem with them is with word choice, namely that **spot** and **notice** do not always mean the same thing.

And this is the same reason that there} is no hobby called "train-noticing."

**Spot** can be a synonym of [espy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/espy?s=t) (**catch sight of**), and most similar to [spy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spy?s=t) (no 9: **to catch sight of suddenly**). It can also mean to **see under difficult circumstances**, to **see something first.**

Note the phrasal verb that is interchangeable with **spot** is **catch sight of**. Please note that in your sentences, *catch sight of* works in the introductory clause but not in the *that*-clause:

5. As caught sight of by some customers, the store does not stock the ...
6. *Some customers caught sight of that the store does not stock the...

> And *caught sight of* does substitute into the article:

7. As caught sight of by 9to5Mac, Apple will trim its iPhone return window from 30 days to 14 as of tomorrow.

It might not sound the best, but Number7 is grammatical and maintains the meaning of the original sentence in the article.

> Please also note that spot can be followed by a *that*-clause:

**9to5Mac spotted that Apple will trim its iPhone return window from 30 days to 14 as of tomorrow.**

{Edit to add: In your Number 4, *spotted* is okay, but it would not be my number one word choice. This is not because *spot* cannot be followed by a *that*-clause, but because spot often means to *see quickly,* and it doesn't make that much sense in Number 4.

Whereas:

(7b) Not only did I spot the deer darting through the woods, I spotted that it was a female [mule deer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_deer).

is fine, to me at least.}

---

The following is just more information.

8. Can you spot the rabbit among the lettuce in the garden?
9. Can you catch sight of the rabbit among the lettuce in the garden?
10. ? Can you notice the rabbit among the lettuce in the garden?

Is Sentence 10 is grammatical? If it is, it does not have the same meaning, because *notice* does not mean the same *as catch sight of* and *spot,* (as used in the sentence).

Can you use spot with a "that" clause. Yes.

**11. I spotted that the number of the train 1/2 mile away through the mist was 23.**
12. *I caught sight of that the number of the train 1/2 mile away through the mist.
13. I noticed that the number of the train 1/2 mile away through the mist was 23.

Here, Number 12 is not grammatical. Numbers 11 and 13 are grammatical. But the meaning of 11 and 13 are not identical.

Comment: I think #12 is grammatical: "I couldn't see the number of the train even when it was just 10 feet away." "Really?? I caught sight of the number of the train [when it was] 1/2 mile away through the mist [no less]."

Comment: @Jim. I had to edit #12 to add the word *that,* which I had omitted.